# Keras fit_generator incorrect input shapes

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tf.keras, keras-2

I'm using an ImageDataGenerator to input batches of images to a neural network, but can't work out the correct way to feed it. Running the following:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/Training', target_size=(256,256), batch_size=32, class_mode='binary', color_mode = 'grayscale')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/Test', target_size=(256,256), batch_size=32, class_mode='binary',color_mode = 'grayscale' )


input_size = (256, 256, 1)
inputs = Input(input_size)
conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
conv2 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
conv3 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv2)
model1 = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = conv3)

model1.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model1.fit_generator(training_set, steps_per_epoch=160, epochs=10, validation_data=test_set, validation_steps=800)
```

Results in:

> Error when checking target: expected conv2d_198 to have 4 dimensions,
>   but got array with shape (14, 1)

It seems to use the batches as the input tensor, since removing all layers but the input layer results in a similar error. How can I correctly input them into the network?

Answer (score 0):

Basically Keras is expecting your to pass your input dimensions and rows. Looks like you are passing an array with two dimensions. Can you make sure you are passing something like (-1, dimension 1, dimension 2, channels) ? you may need to use reshape. The -1 should tell Keras to infer the rows/observations. Im pretty new to Keras so I am sure someone else will have a better answer but you might be able to just do.. myinputarray.reshape()